# How to disable validation property in mvc web api c# that allow html content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a web api that accepts a multipart form request that contains input for text, file fields. Now I'm facing a problem that I cannot send html text through the text field.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SampleController()
{
    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var sendItem = httpRequest.Params["Body"];
    }
}
```

The code above shows the api controller. It accepts a 'Body' field that contains Html contents. When parsing the request by controller caught an Error shown below.

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (`Body="<p><b>Hai</b></p>"`).

Web.config:

```xml
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
</system.web>
```

How to solve this issue so that it can accept text with html?

Comment: You need to encode the html entities before sending them.

Comment: @jgetner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client#comment4192833_81991